# Save email on disk

Tags: macos, backup, email

I'm using Fastmail and its web interface as my email client and I'd like to clean it up but save multiple hundreds of emails to some text-based format.

Is there any macOS email client or utility that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/), with [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/?src=search) plugin.

If you need a step by step guide, [here](http://its.isber.ucsb.edu/guides/exporting-e-mail-thunderbird) is one with images, is quite old, but gives the idea. Use software/plugin from Mozilla site.

Comment: The plugin is a bit buggy when trying to export a folder (it misses many emails from it) but I was able to do it in the end by selecting all the emails and exporting them at once instead. :) Thanks!